# find the text and the strip the text at a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, indexof, strip

I am trying to write this function to grab the text value and then strip the text from after the **-** symbol and the **-** symbol itself. eg

> some text - is found

would become

> some text

This is what iv got so far currently it just removes the **-**

```
$.keynav.enterDown = function () {
      var accom = $('#suggestions p.keynavon').text().replace(/-/g,'');

    alert(accom);

       $('#search input#q').val(accom);
      $("#form").submit();

}
```

Comment: do you mean beside [a-z]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var text = "some text - is found";
var accom = text.split("-")[0];
alert(accom); // some text
```

**[[Demo](http://jsbin.com/idetu4)]**

Answer (score 1):

You can change your regex a bit so it's matching everything after the `-` as well, like this:

```
var accom = $('#suggestions p.keynavon').text().replace(/-.*/,'');
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/c2QnM/2/), if you want the space before the `-` gone, add that as well: `/ -.*/`.

Answer (score 0):

replace will replace all occurence of - from your string with ' ' you need to look for substr function in combination with indexOf